# To find exact result of match from elastic query

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am struggling with searching for elastic data.

please check the below data,

```
"OwnerList": [
                        {
                            "contacttp": "Asset Manager",
                            "artrole": null,
                            "ownerflag": "N",
                            "userid": "sumshett - (Somshekhar Umshetti)",
                            "cecid": "SUMSHETT"
                        },
                        {
                            "contacttp": "Deal Assurance POC",
                            "artrole": null,
                            "ownerflag": "N",
                            "userid": "ngadi - (Neelima Gadi)",
                            "cecid": "NGADI"
                        },
                        {
                            "contacttp": "True-Up Specialist",
                            "artrole": null,
                            "ownerflag": "Y",
                            "userid": "sumshett - (Somshekhar Umshetti)",
                            "cecid": "SUMSHETT"
                        },
                        {
                            "contacttp": "Renewals Manager",
                            "artrole": "CSS ACAT Admin",
                            "ownerflag": "Y",
                            "userid": "richgup3 - (Richa Gupta)",
                            "cecid": "richgup3"
                        },
                        {
                            "contacttp": "True-Up Specialist-Backup",
                            "artrole": "CSS ACAT Admin",
                            "ownerflag": "Y",
                            "userid": "richgup3 - (Richa Gupta)",
                            "cecid": "richgup3"
                        },
                        {
                            "contacttp": "True-Up Specialist-Backup",
                            "artrole": "CSS ACAT Account Maintenance",
                            "ownerflag": "N",
                            "userid": "ngadi - (Neelima Gadi)",
                            "cecid": "ngadi"
                        },
                        {
                            "contacttp": "True-Up Specialist-Backup",
                            "artrole": "CSS ACAT Admin",
                            "ownerflag": "Y",
                            "userid": "mahengup - (Mahendra Gupta)",
                            "cecid": "mahengup"
                        }
                    ]
```

I just want to check that data is found in the above array or not.
for that, I working with the below query, but it not giving the correct output.

I want query that match with same object value like OwnerList.ownerflag and cecid from same object.
but below query matching with any data from array.

```
{
  "size": 1000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "OwnerList.ownerflag": "Y"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "OwnerList.cecid": "ngadi"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you index the entire array as a single document, or every element of the array as a separate document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use nested data type

> Arrays of objects do not work as you would expect: you cannot query
> each object independently of the other objects in the array. If you
> need to be able to do this then you should use the nested data type
> instead of the object data type.

Adding a working example

**Index mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "OwnerList": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to match with the same object value like `OwnerList.ownerflag` and `OwnerList.cecid` from the same object, use the below query

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "OwnerList",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "OwnerList.ownerflag": "Y"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "OwnerList.cecid": "ngadi"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits":{}
    }
  }
}
```

**Since in the index data given above in the question, there is no data that contains `"OwnerList.ownerflag": "Y"` AND  `"OwnerList.cecid": "ngadi"`, therefore the document will not match**